# SQL to find duplicate invoices in Agresso

Tags: sql, group-by, duplicates, having

I'm trying to write some SQL to allow me to pick up possible duplicated entries that will have the same monetary value and transaction date but which may have had the invoice reference input in slightly different ways.

I've looked through the SQL examples using "GROUP" and "HAVING" but I'm going wrong somewhere and my SQL has been lying dormant for a few years.

This is what I have written.

```
SELECT amount, apar_id, trans_date
FROM agltransact
WHERE client='AA' AND period=201704 AND apar_id<>0
GROUP BY amount, apar_id, trans_date
HAVING COUNT(*) >1
ORDER BY apar_id,amount
```

I was hoping that this would return any duplicate amounts (amount) with the same transaction date (trans_date) and the same Supplier ID (apar_id) but it in fact returns data that I don't understand.  This is the output from the first listed Supplier ID on a much longer list containing various suppliers, transaction dates and amounts;

```
Amount  Supp ID Tr Date
-4149   10303   30/06/2016
-3459   10303   30/06/2016
115.3   10303   30/06/2016
138.3   10303   30/06/2016
3343.7  10303   30/06/2016
4010.7  10303   30/06/2016
```

Would anybody be kind enough to point me in the right direction in order to retrieve duplicated amounts under the same transaction date and supplier ID please?

Comment: can you try to explain what type of result you expected?

Comment: Sorry.  I was hoping to show any amounts that had the same values under the same transaction date and supplier number.  We have, for example, expenses being input more than once so the transaction date and supplier are always the same. The "invoice number", however,  could be "Fred Exps July 16" or "Fred Expenses 07-16" thus having a unique invoice reference.  By finding duplicate values under the same supplier and transaction date we could investigate these in order to see if any were duplicated postings.  Thanks for replying.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking in the table with all the transactional information, you should be looking just at the AP control lines which are stored in the asutrans table. This is untested but should get you all the information you need to make an informed choice about whether or not there was an error made.

```
SELECT voucher_no, ext_inv_ref, description, apar_id, amount, trans_date 
FROM asutrans
WHERE (amount, apar_id, trans_date) in
    (
     SELECT amount, apar_id, trans_date
     FROM asutrans
     WHERE client='AA' and period=201704
     GROUP BY amount, apar_id, trans_date
     HAVING count(*) > 1
)
ORDER BY apar_id, amount, trans_date, voucher_no;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also include asuhistr if you are looking is asutrans.